# Class does exist but is not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, classname

I am absolutely baffled bu this. Here's my CSS:

```js
        $(window).load(function(){

           $('.zichtbaar').removeClass('zichtbaar').addClass('verborgen');

           $('#zoekitem').focus();



           $('.letter').on('click', function(){

               $('.zichtbaar').addClass('verborgen').removeClass('zichtbaar');

               var letter = $(this).text();

               var klasse = "LETTER-" + letter;

               var el = $('.' + klasse);
               
               alert(klasse + " - " + el.length);
               
               $('#alfabet-header').html(letter);

               el.addClass('zichtbaar').removeClass('verborgen');

           });

        });
```

```css
        #zoekitem{

         font-size: 1.3em;

        }


        #letter-header{

         height: 32px;

         color: royalblue;

         font-size: 1.5em;

         font-weight: bold;

         overflow: hidden;

        }


        .letter{

         float: left;

         width: 3.7037037037037%;

         cursor: pointer;

         text-align: center;

        }


        #alfabet-header{

         font-size: 5em;

         font-weight: bold;

        }


        .inhoud{

         margin-left: 10%;

        }

        .verborgen{

         display:none;

        }


        #zoek-header{

         font-size: 2em;

        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="letter-header">
           <div class="letter">A</div>

           <div class="letter">B</div>

           <div class="letter">​C</div>

           <div class="letter">​​D</div>

           <div class="letter">​E</div>

           <div class="letter">F</div>

           <div class="letter">​G</div>

           <div class="letter">​H</div>

           <div class="letter">​​I</div>

           <div class="letter">J</div>

           <div class="letter">​​K</div>

           <div class="letter">L</div>

           <div class="letter">​M</div>

           <div class="letter">​N</div>

           <div class="letter">O</div>

           <div class="letter">​P</div>

           <div class="letter">​Q</div>

           <div class="letter">​R</div>

           <div class="letter">​S</div>

           <div class="letter">T</div>

           <div class="letter">​U</div>

           <div class="letter">V</div>

           <div class="letter">​W</div>

           <div class="letter">​X</div>

           <div class="letter">Y</div>

           <div class="letter">Z</div>

           <div class="letter">0-9</div>

        </div>

        <br/>


        <div>

           <div id="alfabet-header"></div>

           <div id="zoek-header" class="verborgen">Zoekresultaten voor:</div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-A verborgen"><a href="www.appels.com" target="_blank">Appels</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.boerenkool.com" target="_blank">Boerenkool</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.bonen.com" target="_blank">Bonen</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.bosbessen.com" target="_blank">Bosbessen</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-C verborgen"><a href="www.citrus.com" target="_blank">Citrus</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-K verborgen"><a href="www.kappertjes.com" target="_blank">Kappertjes</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-T verborgen"><a href="www.tuinbonen.com" target="_blank">Tuinbonen</a></div>

           <div class="inhoud LETTER-W verborgen"><a href="www.wittekool.com" target="_blank">Witte kool</a></div>

        </div>
```

When I click A, B, or T everything is fine; The alert shows the number of elements that have the classname that I'm looking for and displays them. But when I click C, K or W, the elements, although they clearly exist, are not found.

I haven't got the palest shade of a clue as to why this happens.

Comment: You have a lot of `%u200B` zero width spaces in your html markup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got a lot of Unicode zero-width space characters in your HTML source, and in particular there's one at the beginning of the text for the "C" box. When you access the `.text()` of the element, therefore, it's not just "C".

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you manage to find this from the OP's copy-paste ?

Comment: If you paste it into for example JSFiddle it'll highlight them.

Comment: So I cannot simply use the "C" in my HTML? Is that right? Or do I have to access it in a different way in the javascript? What is the solution?

Comment: @johannes the solution is to get rid of the garbage characters in your HTML source. They probably were introduced by some copy/paste operations; I don't know because I know nothing of how you made that source file.

Comment: This happens a lot with Adobe's Dreamweaver more than any other IDE I've seen. There are IDEs with plugins to prevent this, see if yours has one.

Comment: Thanks all. I am making the site in Microsoft Sharepoint. Because I don't like programming in Sharepoint, I made typed the scripts and the html in netbeans and then copy-pasted. Won't do that again.

Answer (score 1):

i just inspect the element. here i found the solution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From @Pointy anwswer, you can remove these zero space, without changing the view. The srcipt to remove these space is `.replace(/\u200B/g,'');`

So your script will be like int his snippet

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    $('.zichtbaar').removeClass('zichtbaar').addClass('verborgen');
    $('#zoekitem').focus();
    $('.letter').on('click', function () {
        $('.zichtbaar').addClass('verborgen').removeClass('zichtbaar');
        var letter = '' + $(this).text().replace(/\u200B/g,'');
        var klasse = "LETTER-" + letter;
        var el = $('.' + klasse);
        alert(klasse + " - " + el.length);
        $('#alfabet-header').html(letter);
        el.addClass('zichtbaar').removeClass('verborgen');
    });
});
```

```css
#zoekitem{
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
#letter-header{
    height: 32px;
    color: royalblue;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.letter{
    float: left;
    width: 3.7037037037037%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
#alfabet-header{
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.inhoud{
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.verborgen{
    display:none;
}
#zoek-header{
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="letter-header">
  <div class="letter">A</div>
  <div class="letter">B</div>
  <div class="letter">​C</div>
  <div class="letter">​​D</div>
  <div class="letter">​E</div>
  <div class="letter">F</div>
  <div class="letter">​G</div>
  <div class="letter">​H</div>
  <div class="letter">​​I</div>
  <div class="letter">J</div>
  <div class="letter">​​K</div>
  <div class="letter">L</div>
  <div class="letter">​M</div>
  <div class="letter">​N</div>
  <div class="letter">O</div>
  <div class="letter">​P</div>
  <div class="letter">​Q</div>
  <div class="letter">​R</div>
  <div class="letter">​S</div>
  <div class="letter">T</div>
  <div class="letter">​U</div>
  <div class="letter">V</div>
  <div class="letter">​W</div>
  <div class="letter">​X</div>
  <div class="letter">Y</div>
  <div class="letter">Z</div>
  <div class="letter">0-9</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <div id="alfabet-header"></div>
  <div id="zoek-header" class="verborgen">Zoekresultaten voor:</div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-A verborgen"><a href="www.appels.com" target="_blank">Appels</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.boerenkool.com" target="_blank">Boerenkool</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.bonen.com" target="_blank">Bonen</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.bosbessen.com" target="_blank">Bosbessen</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-C verborgen"><a href="www.citrus.com" target="_blank">Citrus</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-K verborgen"><a href="www.kappertjes.com" target="_blank">Kappertjes</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-T verborgen"><a href="www.tuinbonen.com" target="_blank">Tuinbonen</a></div>
  <div class="inhoud LETTER-W verborgen"><a href="www.wittekool.com" target="_blank">Witte kool</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just fixing the HTML source?

Comment: because the source of view may not under his control

Answer (score 0):

Removed unwanted Unicode characters.. check below snippet

```js
$(window).load(function(){
       $('.zichtbaar').removeClass('zichtbaar').addClass('verborgen');
       $('#zoekitem').focus();
       $('.letter').on('click', function(){
           $('.zichtbaar').addClass('verborgen').removeClass('zichtbaar');
           var letter = $(this).text();
           var klasse = "LETTER-" + letter;
           var el = $('.' + klasse);
           alert(klasse + " - " + el.length);
           $('#alfabet-header').html(letter);
           el.addClass('zichtbaar').removeClass('verborgen');
       });
    });
```

```css
#zoekitem{
     font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    #letter-header{
     height: 32px;
     color: royalblue;
     font-size: 1.5em;
     font-weight: bold;
     overflow: hidden;
    }
    .letter{
     float: left;
     width: 3.7037037037037%;
     cursor: pointer;
     text-align: center;
    }
    #alfabet-header{
     font-size: 5em;
     font-weight: bold;
    }
    .inhoud{
     margin-left: 10%;
    }
    .verborgen{
     display:none;
    }
    #zoek-header{
     font-size: 2em;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="letter-header">
       <div class="letter">A</div>
       <div class="letter">B</div>
       <div class="letter">C</div>
       <div class="letter">D</div>
       <div class="letter">E</div>
       <div class="letter">F</div>
       <div class="letter">G</div>
       <div class="letter">H</div>
       <div class="letter">I</div>
       <div class="letter">J</div>
       <div class="letter">K</div>
       <div class="letter">L</div>
       <div class="letter">M</div>
       <div class="letter">N</div>
       <div class="letter">O</div>
       <div class="letter">P</div>
       <div class="letter">Q</div>
       <div class="letter">R</div>
       <div class="letter">S</div>
       <div class="letter">T</div>
       <div class="letter">U</div>
       <div class="letter">V</div>
       <div class="letter">W</div>
       <div class="letter">X</div>
       <div class="letter">Y</div>
       <div class="letter">Z</div>
       <div class="letter">0-9</div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
       <div id="alfabet-header"></div>
       <div id="zoek-header" class="verborgen">Zoekresultaten voor:</div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-A verborgen"><a href="www.appels.com" target="_blank">Appels</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.boerenkool.com" target="_blank">Boerenkool</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.bonen.com" target="_blank">Bonen</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-B verborgen"><a href="www.bosbessen.com" target="_blank">Bosbessen</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-C verborgen"><a href="www.citrus.com" target="_blank">Citrus</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-K verborgen"><a href="www.kappertjes.com" target="_blank">Kappertjes</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-T verborgen"><a href="www.tuinbonen.com" target="_blank">Tuinbonen</a></div>
       <div class="inhoud LETTER-W verborgen"><a href="www.wittekool.com" target="_blank">Witte kool</a></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is also solved if you copy my letter-header div here: these are free of NULL bytes.

```
<div class="letter">A</div>
       <div class="letter">B</div>
       <div class="letter">C</div>
       <div class="letter">D</div>
       <div class="letter">E</div>
       <div class="letter">F</div>
       <div class="letter">G</div>
       <div class="letter">H</div>
       <div class="letter">I</div>
       <div class="letter">J</div>
       <div class="letter">K</div>
       <div class="letter">L</div>
       <div class="letter">M</div>
       <div class="letter">N</div>
       <div class="letter">O</div>
       <div class="letter">P</div>
       <div class="letter">Q</div>
       <div class="letter">R</div>
       <div class="letter">S</div>
       <div class="letter">T</div>
       <div class="letter">U</div>
       <div class="letter">V</div>
       <div class="letter">W</div>
       <div class="letter">X</div>
       <div class="letter">Y</div>
       <div class="letter">Z</div>
       <div class="letter">0-9</div>
```